# You are given the postorder traversal, P, of a binary search tree on the n elements 1,2,…,n

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

You are given the postorder traversal, P,  of a binary search tree on the n elements 1,2,…,n. You have to determine the unique binary search tree that has P as its postorder traversal. What is the time complexity of the most efficient algorithm for doing this?

A. Θ(logn)

B. Θ(n)

C. Θ(nlogn)

D. None of the above, as the tree cannot be uniquely determined

My Understanding:

From a given postorder traversal, we can calculate inorder traversal in lg(n) time. since we calculated the inorder traversal now we can split the elements into two parts as root element will be our pivot element.

I don't know i'm understanding it correctly or not, can you help me to visualize the concept.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be `Θ(nlogn)`. You will have to traverse through the n nodes at least and then build the binary tree.

An example from preoder traversal can be like the following. You can apply similar logic for postorder. It uses recursion.

Logic is as we iterate from left to right we will first get the set of elements which are less than the first node. Those nodes will go the left of the node. And the rest will be on the right side.

Eg:

```
Input: [8,5,1,7,10,12]
Output: [8,5,10,1,7,null,12]
```

[image]

The Java code for that:

```
public TreeNode bstFromPreorder(int[] preorder) {
    if(preorder == null) { return null; }

    if(preorder.length == 0) { return null; }

    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(preorder[0]);

    if(preorder.length == 1) {
        root.left = null;
        root.right = null;
        return root;
    }

    int leftStart = 0;
    if( preorder[1] < preorder[0]) {
        leftStart = 1;
    }

    int rightStart = leftStart+1;

    while(rightStart < preorder.length && preorder[rightStart] < preorder[0]) {
        rightStart++;
    }

    int[] leftPre = new int[0];
    if(leftStart != 0) { 
        leftPre = getSubArray(preorder, leftStart, rightStart);
    }
    int[] rightPre = getSubArray(preorder, rightStart, preorder.length);

    TreeNode leftNode = bstFromPreorder(leftPre);
    TreeNode rightNode = bstFromPreorder(rightPre);

    root.left = leftNode;
    root.right = rightNode;

    return root;  
}


private int[] getSubArray(int[] nums, int leftStart, int rightStart) {
    int[] ans = new int[rightStart - leftStart];

    for(int i = leftStart; i < rightStart; i++) {
        ans[i - leftStart] = nums[i];
    }
    return ans; 
}
```